# How to create a Sine Wave Clipper in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a Custom Clipper like the image below.

[image]

Comment: post your `CustomClipper<Path>` then

Comment: Can you show what you achieved so far?

Comment: @pskink I don't know how to draw this path. That's what I want to know.

Comment: @pskink that part I figured. But I need to return path inside getClip right. That I don't know how to do

Comment: @Alastar Please check https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/08/flutter-draw-custom-shaps-clip-path.html I didn't find the wave I want to draw there.

Comment: you need multiple `Path.cubicTo` methods with half of them on the lower part of your wave and half of them on the upper part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

**Clip Widget**

```
ClipPath(
   child: Container(
      height: 8,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.white,
   ),
   clipper: WaveClipper(),
),
```

**Wave Clipper**

```
class WaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    var x = 0.0;
    var numberOfWaves = 30;
    var increment = size.width / numberOfWaves;
    bool startFromTop = false;

    while (x < size.width) {
      if (startFromTop) {
        path.lineTo(x, 0);
        path.cubicTo(x + increment / 2, 0, x + increment / 2, size.height,
            x + increment, size.height);
      } else {
        path.lineTo(x, size.height);
        path.cubicTo(x + increment / 2, size.height, x + increment / 2, 0,
            x + increment, 0);
      }
      x += increment;
      startFromTop = !startFromTop;
    }

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: btw you dont need `path.lineTo(x, 0);` and `path.lineTo(x, size.height);` before calling `path.cubicTo`

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: ClipPath(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          clipper: CustomClipPath(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, 40.0);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 40.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            size.width - (size.width / 16) - (i * size.width / 8),
            0.0,
            size.width - ((i + 1) * size.width / 8),
            size.height - 160);
      } else {
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            size.width - (size.width / 16) - (i * size.width / 8),
            size.height - 120,
            size.width - ((i + 1) * size.width / 8),
            size.height - 160);
      }
    }

    path.lineTo(0.0, 40.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```